# Let the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and the hyperbola $\dfrac{x^2}{A^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{B^2}=1$,

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> > Let the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and the hyperbola $\dfrac{x^2}{A^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{B^2}=1$ be such that their respective end points of latus rectum coincide, then sum of squares of their eccentricities is equal to

(A) $\dfrac{7}{4}$

(B) $2$

(C) $\dfrac{11}{4}$

(D) None

**My Approach:**

Let eccentricity of ellipse and hyperbola be $e$ and $E$ respectively.

It is given that $ae=AE$ and $\dfrac{b^2}{a}=\dfrac{B^2}{A}.......(1)$

Hence $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$ and $B^2=A^2(E^2-1)$

$\implies e^2=1-\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}$ and $E^2=\dfrac{B^2}{A^2}-1$

$\implies e^2+E^2=\dfrac{B^2}{A^2}-\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}$

$\implies e^2+E^2=\dfrac{b^2}{A^2}\bigg(\dfrac{B^2}{b^2}-\dfrac{A^2}{a^2}\bigg)$

Using equation $(1)$ we get $e^2+E^2=\dfrac{b^2}{A^2}\bigg(\dfrac{A}{a}-\dfrac{A^2}{a^2}\bigg)$

**How to proceed from here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving as you did,
$$e=\sqrt{(A/a)}$$
$$E=\sqrt{(a/A)}$$
Therefore the value wanted in the question is:
$$\frac{a}{A}+\frac{A}{a}$$
However, without any restrictions given on $a$ or $A$ or any relation between them, we cannot tell any definite value for the squares of eccentricities. So the best possible option to your question is **(d)None**.

Also as you can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ra62rz40gs), changing $a$ or $A$ changes the sum of squares of the eccentricities.